# What kind of singularity of the given function at zero

Tags: complex-analysis

For the function

> $$\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z}$$ the point $z=0$ is

$\textbf{Solution i tried}$- we can write the given function in form $$\frac{1-1+z-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}........}{z}$$

solving further we get $$1-\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+.....$$

from this we can see that given function have removable  singularity at $z=0$ ,but my answer is wrong

Please help

Thankyou.

Comment: No, that is correct.